# How to manage Libraries/jar files in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I might be missing something but how do you manage Java projects in eclipse that need a lot of Jar files. I know maven manages libraries well if there are new updates but maybe I'm missing something, is there a way that eclipse can update new jar files (it would be especially useful for projects using apache-commons, say).

I don't want to sound like asking for a feature request, but I'm looking at if there are ways to keep libraries jar files that a Java project uses to keep them updated automatically the way maven does. With more languages coming with this type of features, finding the right Jar files probably should be easier than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't manage your jar versions for you, and as far as I know it won't do any auto-updating of jars that have newer versions out there.  There's simply not enough information or infrastructure for Eclipse to recognize that a given jar you've added to the classpath is eligible for updating and that you want it updated.

However, there is a Maven plugin for Eclipse called M2Eclipse, which will read a POM and construct a classpath out of jars it finds in the local repository and any remote repositories you've configured.  It behaves largely like Maven does in terms of finding the latest version for a given jar (if you've specified a version range in your POM).

Comment: makes sense. I liked how Maven (the commandline utility) did the same thing, it's really nice to have it on eclipse too.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user libraries and change their content when new versions are available. That way you do not at least need to change the build path of every project. Or you can load sources of the libraries from their svn and use their trunk version. Remember that you can select multiple projects and svn update them at once.